# How is a -r--r--r-- file being modified by an application?

Tags: permissions, macos

I've set some Spotify UI settings in `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Spotify/prefs` that I'd like to keep. I'm having an issue where the application overwrites this file every time it launches. I've tried to prevent this from happening with `chmod a-w prefs` and running `ll` returns that its permissions are `-r--r--r--` with my username as the owner and staff as the group. When I start Spotify, it resets the file to default and changes the permission back to `-rw-r--r--`. I'm never asked for my sudo password during this. How is this happening?

Comment: Possibly the application is simply deleting the file and recreating it (which only requires write permission on the containing directory). In any case, a process run by you can change permissions on a file owned by you - just as you did with `chmod`.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, I had thought deleting required write permissions.

Comment: @bitmaker yes, deleting requires write permissions, but on the directory containing the file, not the file itself.

Comment: You could try `sudo chattr +i the_file` - but spotify would likely complain (`-i to remove`)

Comment: @ibuprofen I think `chattr` is Linux-only. There seems to be something similar with `chflags` on macOS though, but I didn't look too far into it: https://sites.google.com/site/cqnguyen/chflags-chattr

Comment: @ilkkachu: Ah, yes, did not notice that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files and its directory belong to your user.  So the application running as your user has access to do what it likes with them.

In this context, the most likely thing is that Spotify is deleting completely re-writing the file.  This requires write permission on the directory, not the file.

You could try to remove all write permissions (and even `chown root ...` it) from the parent directory:

```
chmod 555 '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Spotify'
```

This might cause other problems with the application, but unfortunately there is very little you can do to prevent the app re-writing the file.

Answer (score 1):

The application can perform change of permissions because it have write permission on the directory where is the file. Also you are owner of the file and you run application with your user so you can change the permissions.

About chmod:
If you umask is set on 222 you can't change on this way the permission of file:

```
$ umask 222
$ chmod 444 aaa/aa
$ ls -l aaa/aa
-r--r--r-- 1 romeo romeo 0 Jun 16 11:08 aaa/aa
$ chmod +w aaa/aa
$ ls -l aaa/aa
-r--r--r-- 1 romeo romeo 0 Jun 16 11:08 aaa/aa
$ chmod 666 aaa/aa
$ ls -l aaa/aa
-rw-rw-rw- 1 romeo romeo 0 Jun 16 11:08 aaa/aa
```

Comment: @PhilipCouling, the app is run as user and user is owner of the file. So I do not see reason app can't change permission. It's other discussion if app do it actually :)

Comment: There's nothing logically stopping the application doing this... but I can't immagine a reason the application developer would have written the code to do it.  It's **really really rare** for this type of thing to exist in code, and when it does exist, the files usually are leave as read-only by the application.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, I just make a a test on RHEL 8 and Spotify did not change the permission of config file.